# High GTMetrix Scores, Yet Very Slow Performance?

Tags: performance, pagespeed, google-developer-tools, gtmetrix

I've spent several hours/days trying to improve the pageload performance for this page. Can somebody give me some advice about what the problem is. I've added lazy loading to the page for the images yet, it is still extremely slow. I've also turned on pagespeed on the server side and enabled several modules to fully optimize the page and compress all files - still very slow performance. Google developer tools shows that there is a very slow TTFB, but as a new developer, I'm having a hard time pinpointing the exact source of the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://dev3.prosupps.com/team

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/dev3.prosupps.com/fnTCblqf

Answer (score 0):

TTFB is an indication that your web server might be slow. It means the time taken to build the web page is high. Some network components like DNS time & connect time also contribute to TTFB.

In your case the DNS time & connect time are low. Thus you should check the module in your back-end code which is generating the team page.

Refer this link [Web Page Optimization](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/time-to-first-byte/)

Comment: So based on this would you cancel out this being a client-side/front-end problem? Thx for the link by the way.

Comment: Just to test, I removed all images except for 5 of them and the load time was fast. Can I learn anything from that?